# array.map cannot export object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am blocking around a semantic problem

I have the expression

```
    if (kate[aa] !== undefined) {
        subK = kate[aa].subKategori.map(x => [{name: x}])
    }
```

where I wanted the output of subK to be

```
[{name : x[0]}, {name: x[1]]
```

however in the console I am getting

```
subK = [[{name:x[0]}],[{name:x[1]}]]
```

which I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x => [{name: x}]` callback creates an array with an object in it for every entry in the array; `map` returns an array of those array.s

If you just want an object, don't use `[]` around the object. Since this is a concise arrow function, you'll need `()` (or use a verbose arrow function):

```
subK = kate[aa].subKategori.map(x => ({name: x}))
```

or the verbose form:

```
subK = kate[aa].subKategori.map(x => {
    return {name: x};
})
```